# Deserialising JSON object with rustc_serialize: why do I need to implement PartialEq?

Tags: json, rust

I have a file containing a JSON object with unknown keys. I would like to decode this object into a structure but don't understand how to declare this structure.

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[derive(RustcDecodable, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    foo: u8,
    bar: Vec<String>,
}

let raw_json = r#"{
    "A": {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": ["a", "b"],
    },
    "C": {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": ["c", "d"],
    },
    :
}"#;

let j: BTreeMap<String, MyStruct> = json::decode(&raw_json).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", j.get("A").unwrap());
```

The following error occurs:

```
error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq` is not implemented for the type `MyStruct` [E0277]
    let j: BTreeMap<String, MyStruct> = json::decode(&raw_json).unwrap();
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Would I have to implement `Decodable` for `MyStruct` myself then?

Comment: Did you try implementing `PartialEq` as the error message suggests?

Comment: No, tbh. I thought the error is incorrect as for this struct equality should be possibly derived. I implemented `PartialEq` now and it works. However, I still don't understand why I need to do so. None of the example online seem to do this.

Comment: *for this struct equality should be possibly derived* — no traits are automatically derived, that's why you have to add `#[derive]`.

Comment: Thanks, I start to get it. Adding `#[derive(PartialEq, ..)]` removes the requirement to implement it by-hand. Will update the title. Apparently I should read more fundamentals of Rust's language instead of diving heads-forward.

Comment: I think that diving head-first should be done hand-in-hand with [reading up on the fundamentals](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/)!

Answer (score 3):

[`json::decode`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/fn.decode.html) is defined as:

```
pub fn decode<T: Decodable>(s: &str) -> DecodeResult<T>
```

This means that given a string slice, it will attempt to be decoded into a type specified by the user, so long as that type implements [`Decodable`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/trait.Decodable.html). On the page for `Decodable`, you can see all the implementations of it, including the one for `BTreeMap`:

```
impl<K: Decodable + PartialEq + Ord,
     V: Decodable + PartialEq>
Decodable for BTreeMap<K, V>
```

This shows that in order to decode to a `BTreeMap`, both the key and value in the map need to be `PartialEq`. However, I wasn't clear on why that is actually needed. `BTreeMap` should only require that the key is `Ord` and not care about the value at all. To that end, I've opened [a pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-serialize/pull/129) to remove those bounds, and it was accepted! ^_^ I guess that means that the bounds might have just been a typo originally.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer as hinted by @Shepmaster is to either implement the `PartialEq` trait or let it be derived, as the error message indicates:

```
#[derive(RustcDecodable, PartialEq, Debug)]
```

Comment: The question isn't 'how do I fix this,' it's 'why do I need it.

Comment: @SteveKlabnik note that you are replying to the OP of the question ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster: Whether the answer is from the OP or not, it still does not answer the question as posed (unlike your answer).